# grep formatted number using r

Tags: r, regex

I have a string format that I would like to select from a character vector. The form is

```
123 123 1234
```

where the two spaces can also be a hyphen. i.e. 3 digits followed by space or hyphen, followed by 3 digits, followed by space or hyphen, followed by 4 digits

I am trying to do this by the following:

```
grep("^([0-9]{3}[ -.])([0-9]{3}[ -.])([0-9]{4}$)",mytext)
```

however this yields:

```
integer(0)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `[ -.]` matches a lot more than just a dot and  a space, you need `[ .-]` if you want to match a dot, hyphen or space.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - OP wants hyphen or space. This should work fine: `grep('^\\d{3}[ -]\\d{3}[ -]\\d{4}$', x)`

Comment: It seems like you have a whitespace at the end of the string. You could either consider that space in your regex or remove the end of the line assertion.

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=x4Wo17bU&version=1)?

Comment: @Thomas - might be simpler to use `value=TRUE` arg to `grep`

Comment: @jbaums I don't know `r`, feel free to correct it :)

Comment: Really, no idea what you are doing, maybe just extract that pattern from a larger string? Like `sub(".*?([0-9]{3}[ .][0-9]{3}[ .][0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", mytext)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string has a whitespace at the end, so you can either consider that white space, like so:

```
grep("^([0-9]{3}[ -.])([0-9]{3}[ -.])([0-9]{4} $)",mytext)
```

Or remove the end of line assertion `"$"`, like so:

```
grep("^([0-9]{3}[ -.])([0-9]{3}[ -.])([0-9]{4})",mytext)
```

Also, as pointed out by  Wiktor Stribiżew, the character class `[ -.]` will match any character in the range between `" "` and `"."`. To match `"-"`,`"."` and `" "` you have to escape the `"-"` or put it at the end of the class. Like `[ \-.]` or `[ .-]`